# Form post not being recognized on the 2nd page

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a very very basic dilemma that i am struggling with @ the moment. I have a Symfony form that posts to another page, essentially user is redirected to template_2 and the form exists on template_1. This I achieve like this:

```
renderFormTag('module/template2');
```

In the action of template_2, I have the following code:

```
if($request->isMethod('post'))
{
  // retrieve form values from the Form available in template 1 
   $params = $this->getRequestParameter('formFieldName');
   echo $params; 

}
```

However, this isn't happening.

Nothing is being echoed out.
I put in an echo "hello" but that does not execute either. 
Infact I put in an echo "hello" outside of the if condition and that does not echo either.

I doublechecked the name of the template and the action , and that part is good.

Can anybody tell me where I am messing up?

Comment: wow...nobody has an answer or this ... ?

Comment: The reason why people havent commented is because something like this should work - can you include your form setup ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the generated HTML whether it is valid or not and then check if the url in form tag is present in the output of `symfony app:routes your_application_name` and if it's accept a POST request and you can check if the right route matched in the dev toolbar.

If it's a symfony generated form, I think `$this->getRequestParameter('formFieldName');` is wrong, because fields in generated form usually encapsulated into an array of the form name... so you should write `$this->getRequestParameter('form_name[form_field_name]');` see the HTML or the base form class for the form name. But **be aware** if you accessing posted values this way (from the request) they'll **never be validated**, it would be batter to recreate the form, validate the submitted data and access them through the form, see an example [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10#chapter_10_sub_the_form_action) (`executeCreate` and `processForm` methods in the action class).